# Sanitizing SQL input in Java when using LIKE

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, indexing, sql-like

We all know that in Java you are supposed to use PreparedStatments to avoid security flaws.

However, I have noticed that when using *LIKE* statements to do a "starts with" search, PreparedStatments can cause performance problems.  Because the statement is compiled without the value, the driver **must** assume that the wildcard could be anywhere, including the beginning so it skips any indexes on that column.  But if you compile the statement with the *LIKE* value as a literal, it sees that it can use the column's index on the value up until the wildcard and the query performs well.

```
//safe, but prepared statement can't use index on MYCOL
String userInput = "myval%";
statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOL LIKE ?");
statement.setString(1, userInput);
rs = statement.executeQuery();


//can use index on MYCOL, but is not safe
statement = conn.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOL LIKE '"+userInput+"'");
```

So how do I avoid the security flaws while keeping the index?  I'm assuming that I'll have to try to sanitize the input instead of using a PreparedStatement -- if so, does a library exist to do it correctly?  Or is there same java.sql or (oracle) database hint way of telling the prepared statement that it will be able to use the index on the value?

Comment: Why not to hint database to use index?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I did mention hints, didn't I. Well, I'd rather not use them, if at all possible.  My query is for a search that could potentially select based on LIKEs on up to 6-7 different columns. I worry that a hint would pick a bad index.....

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a stored_procedure on the database side? That way you can just send the stored_procedure name and the like string as a parameter to the database, and work with the result set on the java side. This way, you know you query will use indexes of the table you are working on.

Comment: In this case, because we are building the SQL dynamically based on 6-7 different columns (see my comment on the question), I'm not sure that moving the problem to the database solves anything.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

create a sql function to do so, or use the second approach and just escape the characters (`'` -->> `''`)

```
String userInput="IBM";
statement = conn.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOL LIKE '"+userInput.replaceAll("'","''")+"%'");
```

Comment: it's escape code like that which leaves you wide open to sql injection attacks...

Comment: I know. I don't know about the MySQL escape characters, but in many systems injection is started with `'`, that you would change it to `''` that means a single quote as user entered.

Comment: @user2511414, I'm with jtahlborn on this one.  Most attacks I've seen begin with a close quote....but I am not willing to risk my data on that being a comprehensive solution.

Comment: I know and agree dude, but it's solution at least, and as I said at the first, it's better to let a procedure do it for you and just call the procedure, or use full-text functions.

Comment: Its been a while since I looked at this question -- I'd still like a response.  The most frustrating thing, I think, is jtahlborn's comment which implies that this particular approach is deficient, but provides to feedback as to why.